# LuisDialog not working anymore after update to 1.2.0.1

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I've updated my NuGet packages to use the version 1.2.0.1 of the Microsoft Bot Framework.

Some breaking changes were [reported here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/releases/tag/NuGet1.2.0.0), and I managed to fix the build errors. But the application is not working anymore..

I have two problems:

1. The code throws an **InvalidIntentHandlerException** when I send a message an utterance to the controller.
2. In my 'intent' method (decorated with the LuisIntent attribute) it was possible to read the value of the entities. Like so:

   ```
   [Serializable]
   [LuisModel("xxxxx", "xxxx")]
   public class BookFlightDialog : LuisDialog<BookFlightForm>
   {
       private readonly BuildFormDelegate<BookFlightForm> BuildForm;

       internal BookFlightDialog(BuildFormDelegate<BookFlightForm> buildForm)
       {
           BuildForm = buildForm;
       }

       [LuisIntent("")]
       [LuisIntent("None")]
       public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
       {
           await context.PostAsync("I'm sorry. I didn't understand you.");

           context.Wait(MessageReceived);
       }

       [LuisIntent("BookAFlight")]
       public async Task BookAFlight(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
       {
           var form = new BookFlightForm();
          // var entities = new List<EntityRecommendation>(result.Entities);

           var locations = result.Entities.Where(e => e.Type.Equals("builtin.geography") || e.Type.Equals("builtin.geography.city")).OrderBy(e => e.StartIndex);

           if (locations.Any())
           {
               form.LocationFrom = locations.First().Name;

               if (locations.Count() == 2)
               {
                   form.LocationTo = locations.Skip(1).First().Name;
               }
           }

           var date = result.Entities.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Type == "builtin.datetime.date");
           if (date != null) form.DepartureDate = DateTime.Parse(date.Name);

           var formDialog = new FormDialog<BookFlightForm>(form, BuildForm, FormOptions.PromptInStart);

           context.Call(formDialog, OnComplete);
       }

       private async Task OnComplete(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<BookFlightForm> result)
       {
           BookFlightForm booking;
           try
           {
               booking = await result;
           }
           catch (OperationCanceledException)
           {
               await context.PostAsync("Ok, see you later.");
               return;
           }

           if (booking != null)
           {
               var service = new SkyScannerService();
               var possibilities = await service.Search(booking);

               await context.PostAsync(possibilities);
           }
           else
           {
               await context.PostAsync("Form returned empty response!");
           }

           context.Wait(MessageReceived);
       }
   }
   ```

How do I fix the exception and how do I read the value of the entities?

Thanks once again!

Comment: Can you share the code if your LuisDialog? The InvalidIntentHandlerException is only being thrown if there Builder is not able to find any intent in the class. 

Regarding reading the entities, I'm not sure what's the issue you are having there. result.Entities is still available.

Comment: @ejadib: I've updated my post with the LuisDialog.

Comment: Are you using the Bot Framework Emulator? I had an issue as well, then I updated the emulator and it all worked.

Comment: @freethinker6: I reinstalled emulator on your advice, but no effect..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are not using inbuilt `LuisResult` class by having `using LuisResult = Bots.Results.LuisResult;`. Replace it with `using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis.Models;`.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe resharper did something there :S